# Problem with ref and box of theorem

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, labels, polyglossia, ref

[image]
Dear all I have a problem when \label and \ref as it is in this minimal example please help me

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{% bookmarks=true,
    unicode=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=green, %black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue, 
    urlcolor=cyan, 
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\newtheorem{theorem}{مبرهنة}[section]

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  [number within= section]% init options
  {definition}% name
  {تعريف}
  % title
  {%
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
{def}% prefix



%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
%-------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\section{1}
\begin{definition}{}{}\label{1}
نسمي
\end{definition}

من
\ref{1}
\section{2}
\begin{theorem}\label{2}
ليكن 
\end{theorem}

\ref{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorems and similar environment in `tcolorbox` have two parameters, the first one is the theorem title and the second is the label suffix which will be added to the label prefix declares as fourth mandatory parameter in tcbtheorem declaration.

In
`\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{}{theo}`

`theo` is the preffix so, when you declare

```
\begin{theorem}{theorem name}{2}
...
\end{theorem}
```

label `theo-2` is created and you can use `\ref{theo-2}` to make a reference to this theorem. Similar behaviour with `definition`. You don't need an external `\label` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{% bookmarks=true,
    unicode=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=green, %black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue, 
    urlcolor=cyan, 
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%\newtheorem{theorem}{مبرهنة}[section]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{}{theo}

\newtcbtheorem
  [number within= section]% init options
  {definition}% name
  {Name}
  % title
  {%
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
{def}% prefix



%-------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
%\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
%\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
%-------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\section{1}
\begin{definition}{Definition name}{1}
نسمي
\end{definition}

من
\ref{def:1}
\section{2}
\begin{theorem}{theorem name}{2}
ليكن 
\end{theorem}

\ref{theo:2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much